# Photoshop color issues

Tags: photoshop

I am having an issue with Photoshop where the project shows in different colors than the project in save for web preview and explorer. I like the color of it in browser but I want Photoshop to show the same!

I have looked everywhere and tried to do it how they say but there is still no fix.

[image: Screenshot 1]

**EDIT:**
The color on the project border is #272425 As you can see here, Photoshop is not showing it correctly..

http://www.color-hex.com/color/272425

**EDIT 2:**

I was messing with the "Save for web" and changed Preview to "Legacy Macintosh(No Color Management) and the preview matched the project in the canvas. Here is a screenshot of it.

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Is it due to a difference in CMYK / RGB?

Comment: I don't know.. CMYK/8 is what it appears the project is. I have no idea what to do. The project you see.. I had to keep editing colors and preview and use the preview to decide the colors.. I have had enough of that I want to fix it.

Comment: You might want to ask questions like this here: http://photo.stackexchange.com/ this site is for questions relating to programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had the same issue, try this : 
open a new file and check the color mode at the beginning. then open up your file again!

Comment: It shows that there is none selected and it works correctly. Now I have a project that I want to convert the profile but I dont know what one to convert to.

Comment: for the color profile try the: sRGB IEC61966-2.1
and the RGB color for the color mode as well

Comment: New projects are fine, Just this one is effed up.. Not a problem anymore i guess. I will make sure I do not select a profile in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you save a file it gives you various colour management profiles depending on your set up (or needs). If you save without any colour management profile then the colours will be true

Answer (score 0):

May be you are using CMYK color mode. try to change it. go to image then mode and click RGB color. RGB use for displaying purpose while CMYK Mode use for Printing purpose. Since this is web site item design, select RGB Color mode.

Answer (score 0):

The export for web uses sRGB. You use US Web Coated. Change your document to RGB mode and sRGB profile.

The sRGB color is the smallest RGB color space. 
You typically always work in the smallest space, even if your screen allows a wider RGB.